# Holiday planner

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to create a holiday planner to keep track of the holiday used by a number of employees. These employees will be split into language teams:

[image: Example table.]

I used this formula to create a monthly selector:

`=INDEX(Settings!C4:C15,'Monthly Sum (2)'!V2)` then

`=IF(D9="","",IF(EOMONTH($D$8,0)>=D9+1,D9+1,""))` then

`=TEXT(D9,"DDD")` to change the days

That works switching between each month and displaying the day.

but I would like to add another tab where it should show the total number of hours asked by employees split as per the second screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

In the first tab every time someone adds a holiday it should be added like this:

`Holiday-number of hours-h`

so for example

```
Holiday-8h 
Holiday-1h
```

and so on.

What formulas or workaround I could use to make this work?

Comment: The first workaround I would use, is not to use a spreadsheet for this. I am sure there are plenty of solutions which would use a database, and that would be the correct workaround. Using a spreadsheet would result in hack upon hack upon hack. How do you keep proper track of holidays used, half days off, unpaid time off, additional holidays for service length, holidays carried forward, holidays relinquished and paid for. Seriously, using a spreadsheet is to setup failure in the future.